# .NET Standard class library auto versioning - VSTS nuget pack & publish

Tags: nuget, versioning, azure-pipelines, .net-standard

I have a NET Standard class library (VS2017) and I created a CI/CD build in VSTS - it gets built, packed into nugget package and pushed to our own nugget feed. Now, I need to have an automated versioning of this library. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, how I made it to work:

1. I added `dotnet pack` build task *v.2.* (preview)*
2. set *Automatic package versioning* to *Use the build number* for the task
3. In **Options** tab I set *Build number format* to `$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:.r)`

And now when the project is built it publishes package with version in this format:

**Version 2017.9.24.1**

So I can now install it this with the command:
`nuget install MyCommonLibrary -version 2017.9.24.1`

Can't see any drawbacks for now.

Comment: You can mark it as answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.

Comment: you can't mark your own answer as an answer. so please do it.

Comment: I'd like to use the project version as the prefix for the build version, as well as add the build date/revision, is that possible? e.g. .csproj contains `<Version>1.0</Version>` and I append the VSTS build so it calls `dotnet pack` with a version `1.0.20180203.01` or somesuch?

Comment: @Quango if you use `<VersionPrefix></VersionPrefix>` instead of `<Version>` then you can pass `--version-suffix $(Build.BuildNumber)` in the Arguments of the `dotnet build` command in VSTS. This will add the build number after your version (eg `1.0.0-ci-2018.01.03`) for the generated assembly. Then when you go to package this version number will be used for the package as well if you select (`Use the build number`) under `Automatic package versioning` for the `dotnet pack` command.

Comment: @seangwright yes I know, but it you update the project properties via VS it does not respect this and won’t update versionprefix